# Intersection of Disks

Tags: geometry, combinatorics, discrete-geometry

If I have a disk $d$ where each point of the disk is contained in at least $k$ other disks, then at least how many other disks does $d$ intersect?

Given, that all the disks (including $d$) have the same radius, and no two disks have the same coordiante.

Comment: yes $d$ too has same radius, but I'm not sure if I understand your remark.

Comment: Oh, I think I get it: each point in $d$ is contained in at least $k$ other disks, but not necessarily the *same* disks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple upper limit is $3k$.  Each disk passes through the center of $d$ and is clocked from the first one by $\frac{2\pi}{3k}$.  If one of the covering disks is allowed to match $d$ we get $3k-2$.  But one can probably do better.